# IF statement is not working as expected

Tags: c#

My `IF` statement is not working as expected and it's bugging me big time. I'm not sure to what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please shed some light on this?

```
var _getData = db.EventTable.Where(x => x.EventID == id && x.Town == town).ToList();

if (_getData != null)
{
    foreach (var e in _getData)
    { 
         // some logic here to update the event etc
    }                          
}
else
{
    // some logic to create an event
}
```

My code never hits the `else` block when the `_getData` is null, I don't know why this is. I need it to hit the else block in order to create an event in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try, for debugging purposes, to just set _getData to null directly? Because unless that doesn't work as well, it simply means _getData is never null.

Comment: Rather than testing for `null`, you should probably be testing *whether the list is empty*.

Comment: `_getData` can be `null` but `ToList()` can return an *empty* list

Comment: Check if your list count is greater than zero rather than null

Comment: "My code never hits the else block when the _getData is null" - can you clarify when this was occurring? As other people have indicated, this *shouldn't* return null.

Comment: while it's true EF won't return null to be safe test for both not null and empty list: i.e.  `(_getData != null && _getData.Count > 0)` - just in case a later release changes the way EF, works or you yourself change the way _getData is populated.  (- Which BTW means ALL of the other solutions presented thus far WILL fail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToList()` can't return `null` but *empty* list:

```
if (_getData.Any()) 
{
  foreach (var e in _getData)
  { 
     // some logic here to update the event etc
  }   
}
else 
{
  // some logic to create an event
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. Now I understand

Comment: @Rawling: `.ToList()` materializes the results, that's why `.Any()` is safe

Answer (score 2):

Even if there are no rows that match the criteria, a list with no entries will be returned.

Solution:

```
if(_getData.Any())
{
    ...
```

To prevent similar errors in the future I strongly suggest naming variables like this:

```
var townEventsList = db.EventTable.Where(x => x.EventID == id && x.Town == town).ToList();

if (townEventsList.Any()) 
{
    foreach (var townEvent in townEventsList)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling ToList() it will have created a List which is being stored in your _getData variable.

Try checking for presence of items in this list by:

```
if (_getData.Any())
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because _getData will never be NULL. Entity Framework does not return NULL if no data is found. It will always return a list even with ZERO items.

You should check the length of the _eventData to find out if you got anything back or not.